# Reading image in two different environnement

Tags: python, image, numpy, python-imaging-library

I have two different environment and an image to read

In both environnment I have :

- PIL == 7.2.0
- numpy == 1.19.1

I run this code (and only this code) in the two environments :

```
import numpy as np
from PIL import Image
res = np.asarray(Image.open(r"C:\Users\MLH\Documents\Notebook Projets\CompteursKm\merge_project\boxes\14.jpg"))
```

But the res array is not identical in the two environment.

I can't figure out why. Can you help me ?

The image in question is :
[image]

From env1 I get :

```
[[[145 100  43],  [144 102  44],  [143 101  43],  ...,  [ 89  50  19],  [ 81  49  28],  [ 63  36  25]],, [[162 115  45],  [162 117  49],  [160 115  47],  ...,  [129  91  55],  [113  79  54],  [ 70  44  29]],, [[164 116  32],  [167 119  37],  [165 118  36],
```

and from env2 I get:

```
[[[145 101  38],  [146 102  39],  [143 102  40],  ...,  [ 86  51  23],  [ 81  49  26],  [ 63  37  24]],, [[160 115  47],  [162 117  49],  [160 115  48],  ...,  [127  91  59],  [111  80  52],  [ 71  43  29]],, [[164 116  34],  [166 119  39],  [165 118  40],
```

**I want to get the env1 result in env2.**

Comment: And, **what exactly** is "not identical"? The shape? The colors? Anything else? What are the two environments?

Comment: When I open the image it looks like the same, but when looking to numbers there are differents (edited my question with part of the results). When you ask "what are the two environments ?" do you want all the librairies installed in them (because there is a lot ...)

Comment: What kind of environments - I guess, you talk about two different virtual environments here!? On the same machine? On different machines? Maybe, the underlying JPEG library used by Pillow is different for both environments, most likely when used on two different systems.

Comment: You are right it is two virtual environment. They are on the same machine. I will check for the jpeg library used

Comment: I checked there https://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/stable/installation.html the JPEG library that can be used. Neither openjpeg or libjpeg is installed (on env1 and env2). Moreover is the potential underlying JPEG library can have impact on my case where my image is a JPG image ?

Comment: Do you get a result when running `print(Image.core.jpeglib_version)`? By the way: If I run the given code on the given image, it seems, I get the results from your env2.

Comment: Thanks ! It seems to be there because for env1 I get 9.0 and for env2 8.0 !

Comment: Do you know how can I update this Image.core.jpeglib for my env2 ?

Comment: Check [this GitHub repo](https://github.com/StarsThu2016/PIL_Load_Debug). Actually, that seems to be your exact issue. There's a guide to update to version 9.0 for some Unix derivate.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To summarise, thanks to @HansHirse we found that the issue was that `Image.core.jpeglib_version` was different.

To install the version 9.0,  I did :

```
pip uninstall pillow
conda install pillow
```

(if I did `pip install pillow`, I got version 8.0)

I don't really understand why, but it is working :)

Comment: Ah, your environments have different package managers! You should've mentioned that! ;-) Most likely, the Windows packages of Pillow were simply built differently for `pip` and `conda`, one linking against `libjpeg` 8.0, the other against `libjpeg` 9.0.